# How to properly handle sessions in a Python API wrapper for long-lived instances?

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, python-requests

Evening, I'm currently in the process of writing a module to interact with a public API. My personal use-case for this wrapper is for use within a discord bot.

The API itself isn't structured in a particularly good way, which results in hitting many different endpoints before you gathered all the relevant data.

To me this sounded like the perfect opportunity to `requests.Session`'s, since it'll speed up subsequent requests.

Now, I'm struggling to properly handle sessions in the class itself. I feel like the session is an implementation detail, which shouldn't be left for the user to provide.

Here is a little example:

```py
from requests import request, Response


class APIWrapper:
    def __init__(self, token: str) -> None:
        self.base_url = "https://example.com"
        self.headers = {
            "User-Agent": "my-awesome-thing/python-requests",
            "Bearer": token,
        }

    def _make_request(
        self,
        method: str,
        endpoint: str,
        params: dict | None = {},
        data: dict | None = {},
    ) -> dict:
        resp = request(
            method,
            f"{self.base_url}{endpoint}",
            params=params,
            data=data,
            headers=self.headers,
        )

        return resp if resp.ok else resp.raise_for_status()

    def get_a_thing(self, id: int) -> Response:
        endpoint = "/a/thing"
        params = {"id": id}

        return self._make_request("GET", endpoint, params=params)

    def create_b_with_a(self, a: str) -> Response:
        endpoint = "/b"
        data = {"stuff": a}

        return self._make_request("POST", endpoint, data=data)

    def get_b_thing(self) -> Response:
        endpoint = "/b/thing"

        return self._make_request("GET", endpoint)

    def create_c_with_a_and_b(self, a: str, b: str) -> Response:
        endpoint = "/c"
        data = {"fields": {"a": a, "b": b}}

        return self._make_request("POST", endpoint, data=data)


from random import randrange
from sys import maxsize

api = APIWrapper(token="abc123")

# simulates an eventloop ie. discord bot or fastapi App()
while True:
    a = api.get_a_thing(randrange(maxsize))
    b = api.create_b_with_a(a.json()["data"])
    c = api.create_c_with_a_and_b(a.json()["data"], b.json()["data"])
```

What would be the appropriate way to handle sessions?
The main problem I am facing is, that I don't really understand the lifetime of a `Session`. One instance of `APIWrapper` might live for weeks and it's unlikely that a session can live that long? Otherwise it'd be possible to simply instantiate one in the `__init__` and assign it as an instance var.

Looking forward to insight and suggestions.
Cheers